# Web3 Listening event err

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

i am using web3 suscribe event for listening to incoming and outgoing transaction from rinkeby testnet. but i am not getting anything in console.even my transaction is succesful.

i use infura websocket provider

here is my code

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const webs3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('wss://rinkeby.infura.io/ws/v3/projectid'));
var subscription = webs3.eth.subscribe('logs', {
  address: '0x20617a33cf37387F35e0DA32aBdaDAF09D46B351',
  topics: [null]
}, function(error, result){
  if (!error)
      console.log(result);
})
.on("data", function(log){
  console.log(log);
})
.on("changed", function(log){
});

// unsubscribes the subscription
subscription.unsubscribe(function(error, success){
  if(success)
      console.log('Successfully unsubscribed!');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are subscribing to a "null" events, from the topic parameter on the code you shared which doesn't exists.

Comment: So what topic should i enter

Comment: It should be like this if your are subscribing to transfer events.
 
```
"topics":["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef"] // this is the topic which is "Transfer" in keccak format
 ```